# How can I get git clone --recursive A B to use the submodule repositories in A?

Tags: git, git-submodules

It seems that if project A has submodules with remote urls, then `git clone --recursive A B` insists on pulling down copies of each submodule repository from the remote url.  Is there a way to get git to clone the submodule repositories from the copies in A instead of pulling from the remote repositories?

I suppose I could do something like:

```
git clone A B
cd A
git submodule --quiet foreach 'echo [submodule \"$path\"]\\n path = $path\\n url = $toplevel/$path ' > ../B/.gitmodules
cd ../B
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive
git checkout .gitmodules
cd ..
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is local?

```
cp -r A B
```

[response to comment]

If A is dirty, then:

```
   (cd A; git stash)
   cp -r A B
   (cd B; git stash drop)
   (cd A; git stash apply)
```

Comment: Yes, that's great, but it also copies local changes to the repository if the A repository is dirty.  But yeah, if A is clean, that looks like a good solution.