# How can I get 'git clone --recursive' to clone submodules locally?

Tags: git, clone, git-submodules

I'm in the habit of making a git clone to a master location on my disk and then using a local git clone from there to cut down on download and copy times.

However, if I clone a project that has submodules, `git clone --recursive`, it will use `--local` for the main repo, but the submodule initialization is still by reference to URLS, which means I'm still going and doing a download again.

Is there a way to make `git clone --recursive` clone from the local copies of submodules instead of the canonical locations?

Comment: I've done this by doing `git clone`, then editing the `url` for each entry to point to my local repo + the path from that same entry, and it does what I want.  It feels like there ought to be a better way though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get git clone --recursive A B to use the the submodule repositories in A?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932275/how-can-i-get-git-clone-recursive-a-b-to-use-the-the-submodule-repositories-in)

Answer (score 0):

this is my savior always:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This, initializes submodules and clones them even if you have submodules within submodules. 
I have an alias in my bash_profile for this and always use this for empty repositories and for simple update operations

```
alias gsu='git submodule update --init --recursive'
```

Comment: Right, but it clones it from the canonical source:

If I clone from github to /srv, and then from /srv to my /home, the recursive bit from /srv to /home still hits the canonical URL (github in this case) for the submodules, instead of cloning from /srv/foo/submodule.  I'm trying to do a completely offline git clone, and it seems I can't without updating .gitmodules directly :-(

Comment: oh, sorry then! your question wasn't clear for me at first sight. Can't you set the source manually for all submodules? But why would you need that in the first place? I mean, can't you just make another sourse on github ?